# Can I make programs for Windows CE in VB.NET 2010?

Tags: vb.net, windows-ce, vb.net-2010

...Or do I have to use VB 2006 and/or lower? I heard that you can develop programs for **WinCE** in **VB** so I just want to know if that info *is* correct and if Yes, then do I need to use one of the older versions of VB, or can I use VB 2010? ***(Yes I know that is not really the current version but I prefer '10 over '13.)***

Comment: Windows CE ate a poisoned apple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you have to install Visual Studio 2008

Micorsoft dropped Support for Compact Framework in Visual Studio 2010 in favour of Windows Phone platform.

However, you can compile Compact Framework projects with visual studio 2010
(I use Visual Studio to develop for Windows CE but our build server has only 2010 installed)

You have to install .NET Compact Framework 3.5 Redistributable

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=e3821449-3c6b-42f1-9fd9-0041345b3385&displaylang=en

and optional Power Toys for .NET Compact Framework 3.5

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c8174c14-a27d-4148-bf01-86c2e0953eab&displaylang=en

For Visual Studio 2008, you have to own at least a standard or profession version, since the express version can not target Windows CE

That said: At the end you do not have to use Visual Studio at all you can use the command line or SharpDevelop This post is worth reading.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31861/Windows-Mobile-Development-Without-Visual-Studio

Comment: Thank you for the answer I will try the links above

Comment: ****Noob question incoming**** Now that I installed .NET CE Framework redistributable, how do I compile with it?

Comment: @Supercoder - I added another link - but to be honest I would buy visual studio 2008 if you plan to do something bigger. Or you can download your evaluation copy here http://msdn.microsoft.com/evalcenter/bb633753.aspx and after the trial is over use `msbuild.exe` commandline to build your solution.

Answer (score 1):

[There is a CF plug-in for Studio 2013 available commercially here](http://ifactr.com/platform/modernization-framework/visual-studio-2013-compact-framework-plugin).  I know almost nothing about it and have never used it (just came to my attention yesterday) so I'm not endorsing it, but it's worth mentioning.